# JS code working in chrome and IE, not in safari and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, browser

I have the below js code that is working in chrome and IE but not safari and firefox. In both cases, the beforeSend: function works, but the success function does not work.  Is this a problem with the CSS or am I missing something in the javascript?

---JS----

```
    $("#updateBidButton").click(function () {
        var bid_amount = document.getElementById("auction_bid_input").value;
        var item_id = "<?php echo $this->item['id']?>";
        var current_bid = "<?php echo $this->item['current_bid']?>";
        var url_view = "<?php echo $this->item['url_view']?>";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "?module=items&controller=index&action=submitBid",
            dataType: "text",
            data: 'bid_amount=' + bid_amount + '&item_id=' + item_id + '&current_bid=' + current_bid + '&url_view=' + url_view,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.auction_box').animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#ffdead'
                }, 400);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == 'ok') {

                    $.get(window.location.href, function (data) {
                        $('.auction_box').animate({
                            'backgroundColor': '#A3D1A3'
                        }, 400);
                    });
                } else {
                    alert(result);
                        $('.auction_box').animate({
                            'backgroundColor': '#FFBFBF'
                        }, 400);
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Here is the html:

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div id="<?php echo $this->item['id']; ?>">
            <div class="auction_bid_box">
                <label for="auction_bid_input">
                    <!-- Starting bid EXISTS -->
                    <?php if ($this->item['bid_count'] >= '1') { ?>
                        You have until <?php echo $this->data['item']['auction_start']; ?> to update the current bid.
                        <!-- Starting bid is MISSING-->
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        You have until <?php echo $this->data['item']['auction_start']; ?> to enter a starting bid.
                    <?php } ?>

                </label>
            <span class="auction_bid_container">
                <input id="auction_bid_input" type="text" maxlength="12"
                       class="middle nmr event-clear-focus"
                       name="bid_amount" value="Enter Bid"/>
                <input id="updateBidButton" type="submit"
                       value="<?php echo $this->translate('Update'); ?>"
                       class="button grey-button num-items-button"/>
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work in the `success` function? Have you tried debugging this with `console.log` or the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`)?

Comment: @Xufox it never makes it to url: "?module=items&controller=index&action=submitBid"  Weird because it all works in chrome and ie.  There is lots of stuff in the console, most of it css. I can't make heads or tales of what is going wrong. I'd show you the console printout but can't paste it all in here.

Comment: It never makes the request? Meaning if you goto the Network tab of the dev tools it doesn't show a request to that url? You should also add in a error callback in the event of the request causing / receiving an error (parse error, etc)

Comment: @PatrickEvans in the network tab, I dont see a bunch of GETs, but none to that url.  When I look at the network tab in chrome, it clearly requests that URL. I'm not sure how to add in an error callback. sorry.

Comment: If you don't see a request at all then your $.ajax() call is never made, which might mean your click event callback is never called. Might need to add in console log messages within the callback to make sure it is getting called